# What's appication ID and how do i use it?

Tags: gtk, gnome, gtkmm

In a Gtkmm application, one of the first line is:

```cpp
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc,argv,"org.gtkmm.examples.base");
```

I know that `org.gtkmm.examples.base` is an application ID. Some questions about application IDs:

1. What is an application ID?
2. What is the purpose of an application ID?
3. How do I write it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I set the Application ID to in GTK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260126/what-should-i-set-the-application-id-to-in-gtk)

Comment: i have already seen that but i want to know why we use it ? or What are the benefits of it ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gio::Application Class Reference](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGio_1_1Application.html):

> One of the core features that Application provides is process uniqueness, in the context of a "session". The session concept is platform-dependent, but corresponds roughly to a graphical desktop login. When your application is launched again, its arguments are passed through platform communication to the already running program. The already running instance of the program is called the primary instance.

When I initiate two instances of the same program with the same application identifier, the second instance does not create a new window.  Instead it sends a signal to the first and then exits.  If I initiate two instances of the same program with different application identifiers, the two instances run independently.

To specifically answer your questions 1 and 2, it seems from the above that an application identifier identifies the primary instance of an application.  If a second instance is initiated with the same application identifier, the second instance sends a message to the primary instance instead of creating a new primary instance.  This could be used to implement features of the kind found in some web browsers where a second initiation of the program displays the web page in a new tab instead of a new window.